# Could I make a Google Chrome extension for chrome pages (downloads, extensions etc)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to make a very simple extensions that slightly alters how the Downloads page looks. Changing the History page might be interesting too, but that's for later.

Is there a way to do that?

I tried making a [`Content Script`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) extension, with `"chrome://downloads"` as `match` in `manifest.json`. Chrome won't allow that and responds with an error when packaging the extension.

**Is there another simple way?** It has to be simple, because changes would be simple, because all `chrome://` pages are built with HTML, JS and CSS.

**edit**
After trying with background scripts a little...

I can't get `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to work! I added in `background.html`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    alert(this.document.body.innerHTML);
    alert(chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code : "document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';"
    }));
});
```

And I added this in `manifest.json` to add a (invisible) 'browser action button':

```
    ,"browser_action": {
/*      "popup": "background.html",*/
        "name": "Alter page"
    }
```

The `onClicked` event fires both alerts (first is `background.html`'s body, second is `undefined`). But the code (a string with `document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';`) doesn't execute! And ofcourse there's no debugging for extensions like this =)

Any tips anyone? I'm trying to get a hold of the tab's `window.document` (**not** `background.html`'s `window.document`!). An injected script (that's what `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is supposed to do) should do that.

**PS**
I'm stealing from [make_page_red/manifest](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red/manifest.json?content-type=text/plain) and [make_page_red/background.html](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red/background.html?content-type=text/plain)
The 'extension' I have so far: http://hotblocks.nl/js/downloads.rar

**EDIT**
I found out what I want to achieve is possible with just CSS. I don't need to inject javascript. Does that make it easier? Does that make it possible? =)

Answer (score 4):

According to [this documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html), `chrome://` URLs are an invalid scheme so they won't be matched:

> A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with a permitted scheme (`http`, `https`, `file`, or `ftp`), and that can contain '`*`' characters.

I would look into using [override pages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html) instead.

---

As requested, here's my extension that can at least load when `chrome://downloads` is loaded, although as I said, I don't think you can modify the page even if you know that's the page you're viewing.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "background_page": "background.html",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

**background.html**

```
<script>
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab)
    {
        if (tab.status == "complete")
        {
            alert(tab.url);
            // should alert 'chrome://downloads' on that page. You can 
            // check for this url here and then do whatever you want
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It seems only `bookmarks, history and newtab` are overridable like that... I'm specifically looking for `downloads` =(

Comment: Looks like it's not an option at this point then, which isn't surprising: `chrome://downloads` is a special page with access to the user's filesystem, so it has different implications for opening itself up. But what I said with content scripts is still true: `chrome://` URLs are an invalid scheme. I'm going to do a quick bit of research into another method, hang on.

Comment: I was able to make a background script fire when `chrome://downloads` was loaded, but I'm guessing I'll still have the same issues as before if I try to modify that page's content, since that would rely on a content script. I'd be happy to be proven wrong, but for now, I'm going to say that it's locked down.

Comment: But some extensions can even save files to the filesystem. The Downloads page only links to files on the filesystem (that's not so dangerous!?). The problem - so it seems - is to hook the extension into the Downloads page...

Comment: What extension saves files to the filesystem? Are you sure you're not thinking of local storage or a redirect to a regular hosted file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Amazing Screenshot` (or something like that) can edit and then save images. With a dialog ofcourse! But still... But that doesn't matter! I don't want to write to the filesystem. How did you get a script to run on `chrome://downloads`?? I'll take that =)

Comment: I added what I had. I tooled around Awesome Screenshot for a bit, didn't really find anything. Nonetheless, I do think the `chrome://downloads` page is blocked from content script/modification access.

Comment: I'm not giving up! But it's alright if you do =) Thanks, Jimmy! I'm tooling around with it.

Comment: Well, `chrome.tabs.update()` will work - as far as redirecting to another page. However, trying to update the tab to `{ url: "javascript: alert(':)');" }` will not work. But, using a JS bookmark on the downloads page will work.

Comment: "Screengrab" extensions use `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()` and then save the image data within local storage, not as an actual file to a specific location on your harddrive. There is no Chrome API for handling downloads right now.

Comment: @Nexxeus I'm not trying to redirect to another page... @Chris I'm not trying to get a screengrab... I'm trying to inject stuff into the DOM and alter what's already there (on `chrome://downloads/`)

Comment: That's why I mentioned the `javascript: alert('')` approach.

Comment: Nobody knows a way to get to the DOM of the chrome://downloads/ page in a Chrome extension?? **Automatically, every page load, without clicking a bookmarklet or `browser_action`**

Answer (score 3):

Update: Since Chrome 31 there is an API for extensions that allows access to Chrome's downloads: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads

There's also an API that allows access to list and manage other installed extensions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management

---

(Previous Answer)

Unfortunately, there's not currently an API for Chrome extensions to access information about a user's downloads. It's a widely requested feature, though, and there's some discussion among Chrome developers here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12133

Star the issue if it's a feature that you'd like to see, and you'll receive email updates.

Answer (score 1):

[As this page shows, there is no API to override the downloads page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html)... However, there is a way to make a file you have made replace the `chrome://downloads/` page whenever it is loaded using javascript in your `background page`...

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
  if(changeInfo.status === "loading"){
    if(tab.url === "chrome://downloads/"){
      chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "REPLACEMENT.html"});
    } 
  }
});
```

Essentially what this does is - As soon as the page `chrome://downloads` begins loading (using the [tabs.onUpdated API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated)), the page is redirected to `REPLACEMENT.html` (Using [tabs.update API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update))... There is no visible delay in the tab update 
as this script is run before the `chrome://downloads` page begins loading... You can use a similar code in your file by pressing CTRL + U on the downloads page to view and copy its source code

Comment: Will the right variables be available on that new page? Maybe they come from `chrome.*` which is always available... I'm gonna try that! Thanks for the reply. I'll let you know =)

Comment: That didn't work =( Replacing with a new page works. There is however a visible delay. (The page is already rendered when the `onUpdated` event triggers.) That's not the problem though. The new page doesn't have the same rights as the original: function `chrome.send` doesn't exist, which means the downloads can't be retrieved (and shown). It's all about rights =( Maybe if I give my extension more `permissions`? Right now they're `['tabs', 'http://*/*']`