# Run a JS Userscript through Tampermonkey on a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, userscripts, tampermonkey

I have a working JS Userscript intended for running an action when clicking on any word in a webpage.  This works fine when installed either with Greasemonkey in Firefox or Tampermonkey in Chrome on all webpages.

However, I would like for the script to be able to be run (or perhaps have access to run) on a Chrome Extension, specifically the open-source EPUB reader Readium.  This is a type of Chrome extension that installs with an icon, and opens up a new tab with a URL starting with "chrome-extension://...".

Userscripts have the ability to include and exclude websites with a set of tags at the top of the page, and I've attempted to include all websites, all sites beginning with :chrome-extension", all anything, etc., and not only is the code not working, Tampermonkey is not showing that the script is running and the console is not logging any test examples.

So my question is, is there any way to run Chrome Extension/app A, downloaded from the Chrome store, and have Userscript B, running through Tampermonkey, inject JS code into the chrome extension A?

Comment: Duplicate of [Could I make a Google Chrome extension for chrome pages (downloads, extensions etc)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805359/could-i-make-a-google-chrome-extension-for-chrome-pages-downloads-extensions-e), and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148487/can-i-modify-chrome-extensions-page-with-javascriptuser-script, and a few others.